# How can I perform a union and left-join in the same select statement?

Tags: sql, left-join, union

Preface: I am new to SQL and don't know a lot yet, but I am trying to learn.

I want to union two tables (one with old data and one with new data--each has the same fields).

Then, I was to left-join with 'ID'.

The code below is what I've been trying, but it is not working out.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM    clients
LEFT JOIN new_data
(
    SELECT * FROM old_data
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM new_data
)
ON clients.cust_id = new_data.cust_id;
```

SQL Error [500150] [HY000]: Amazon Error setting/closing connection: Not Connected.

Comment: before being able to issue a query, you need to connect to a database schema.

Comment: I have already connected to a database schema.

Comment: then you might have been getting errors related to syntax, metadata .. etc. rather than connection. As an example, what you get when you issue `select 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table alias:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM clients c LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM old_data
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM new_data
     ) d
     ON c.cust_id = d.cust_id;
```

Note:  I changed the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` so it doesn't incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  If you really do want to remove duplicates, keep the `UNION`.

Comment: well, I also considered that case, but OP doesn't mention about such error related to syntax I mean.